# How to view joomla user in frontend with profile data?

Tags: joomla-3.4, user, front-end

I use Joomla 3.4.4

I would like to view list of users in front end. Along with username i need to view profile data, email and phone, in front end. Is there and extension/plugin/component available?

I checked many plugins but no one give phone number. They provide registration date, and other data, but for me email and phone no are important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a module or plugin to get this done.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

A shorter way is to download a module which shows your user list and edit the view file (modules/mod_xyz/tmpl/default.php). If not badly written you can just replace unnecessary things.

To know which one you need, just print_r or var_dump your db user object (see zeidanbm answer) like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
die;
```

(Don't do that on a live site.)

You will get a print out of the object and the available fields.

Sorry, can't offer a more detailed answer, I just would write down a complete module...

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to create a new article and insert a php code which will connect to the database and read from the users table. To do that you will need an extension that lets you use php in articles. I personally use Sourcere but you can use any. Here's a sample of the code that can get you started.

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName(array('username', 'email')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($result as $row) {
echo $row->username.'|'.$row->email;
}
?>
```

And for the phone number and other profile things you can do the same but change the name of the table to `__user_profiles`. So the code will look something like below. Also, check the database tables to see the column and row values.

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName(array('profile_key')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($result as $row) {
if( ($row->profile_key) == "profile.phone")
echo $row->profile_value;
}
?>
```

Comment: You may want to think about providing a more up to date database query standard. This is the old method used in J1.5

Comment: @Lodder Thank you. I corrected the code. I guess this is the way it's used in joomla 3.x

Comment: You shouldn't do that in an article.
Just write a simple module.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old, but I came on it searching for something similar. So here it is:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/frontend-user-manager/

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Q&A.  Please avoid posting link-only answers. Take a moment to explain what this extension does and why you believe it is a good idea to use.

Comment: "Is there and extension/plugin/component available?"

Yes. the one mentioned above does exactly what you were looking for three years ago.
Simply written and easily customizable.

Comment: As an edit on your answers instead of a comment please.  I don't mean to harass you, your post was flagged by the system as low-quality because of its length and the fact that half of the character count was in the hyperlink.  I only mean to help you to create a complete and educational post.  Feel free to include any extra features that are nice or mention any drawbacks that you are aware of.